# .ImportXML command erring out in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, xml-parsing, vba

I am using the following code to try to import an XML file to Access:

```
my_file = "c:\temp\projects.xml"
Application.ImportXML (my_file)
```

At some point on the second line I get an error 31550, "Not all of your data was successfully imported. Error descriptions with associated row numbers of bad records can be found in the Microsoft Access table 'ImportErrors'."

I have to End or Debug, and independent of what I choose, the ImportErrors table does not appear in Access. Is there some additional code needed to allow the table to be created? (I had `On Error Resume Next` in there, and that doesn't help.)

Also, if this did work, where would the XML data be loaded? Does Access create a new table?

Comment: You may need to refresh the Tables list in Access. Select (i.e., click on) any existing object (Failing that, just close and re-open Access.)

Comment: Also don't look for a table named just *ImportErrors*.  If it was created, its name will include *ImportErrors* and the import target table name.

Comment: It should also be noted, XML as a data type is an open-ended file type where content can be designed in unlimited structures, nested trees, tags, nodes, etc. distinctly different from a two-dimensional row/column import that tables use. Also, Access only imports element-centric data and not attribute-centric (so, data in tags are ignored). What may be happening is your XML is somewhat complex and does not align to the 2D structure. You need to assess your XML file first (post an abbreviated version), use an xsl transform to a 2D setup, or look into the generalized MSXML VBA object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where would the XML data be loaded? Does Access create a new table?

That depends on the value of the second (optional) *ImportOptions* argument. It can be one of

`acAppendData`
`acStructureAndData`  (the default)
`acStructureOnly`

So for an XML file like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot>
    <foo>
        <FirstName>Gord</FirstName>
        <LastName>Thompson</LastName>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <FirstName>Anne</FirstName>
        <LastName>Elk</LastName>
    </foo>
</dataroot>
```

the VBA statement

```vbs
Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.xml"
```

will create and populate a new table named [foo] (or [foo1] if a table named [foo] already exists), and the command

```vbs
Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.xml", acAppendData
```

will attempt to append the data in the XML file to an existing table named [foo].